# Spring Framework's XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: The prefix "beans" for element "beans:bean" is not bound

Tags: java, spring

I am getting the following error when I pass request to `RestController`.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 22 in XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 108; The
>   prefix "beans" for element "beans:bean" is not bound.
>
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 108; The
>   prefix "beans" for element "beans:bean" is not bound.

Here is the controller:

```
@RestController
public class smsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendSMS", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void sendMessage(@RequestBody MessageBean msgBean) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String numbers = msgBean.getNumbers();    
        String message = msgBean.getMessages();
    }
}
```

And `dispatcher-servlet xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.rest.controllers" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
</beans>
```

Jars on the classpath:

```
jackson-annotations-2.3.2.jar
jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar
jackson-core-2.3.2.jar
```

I am not sure what is causing the problem. When I use new jars of `jackson 2.7.4`, I get another error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo$As

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is obvious and has nothing to do with Jackson:

> The prefix "beans" for element "beans:bean" is not bound.

It says the `beans` prefix or *Namespace* is not defined. Since the `beans` is the default namespace:

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

So you should remove the `beans:` prefix from:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

The end result would be like:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        <list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If you're planning to enable JSON conversion by this piece of configuration, I should say *there is no need for that*. With the presence of the appropriate dependency on the classpath, Spring MVC would automatically register the required `HttpMessageConverter`s for converting from/to JSON. **So you can remove that configuration**.

In the end, your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` would be like the following:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.rest.controllers" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And a word of advice, if you're new to Spring Framework, it's better to start with [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

Comment: It's better to stick with default namespace, since it's make your configuration more concise.

Comment: Is the request handler mapping for jackson required? I am pretty new to this. When I removed the prefix, it throws error `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jsonMessageConverter' is defined`

Comment: If you have `jackson-databind` dependency on the classpth,  yes you can remove that.

Comment: I removed it and when I make a request, I am getting response in browser console: `angular.js:10765 POST http://localhost:8084/AngularSpring/mvc-dispatcher/sendSMS 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: @Satyadev Did you send a JSON as the request body?

Comment: Yes I am sending it as json. I checked. Apparently spring framework4 comes with jackson itseems(research) so I removed the additional jackson jars I added to class path and ran the app and I am getting new error: `415 Unsupported Media Type` in browser

Comment: Changed the jars 2.7.3 jackson worked and ofcourse removing bean prefix helped. Thank you!